# grails: dont save similar domain object again, use present object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The problem:
I have "route" domain, that has stations (domains).
If I save routes, I should save stations too. (used cascade: 'all' mapping)
But, if station with the same name already exists in DB, I want to use it, and don't create such station anymore.
so the route, I save, must save only new stations.

example:
domain:

```
class Route {
    String name
    List<Station> stations

    static mapping = {
        stations cascade: 'all', lazy: false
    }
    static hasMany = [
        stations: Station
    ]
}

class Station {
   String name
}
```

controller/service:

```
def route = new Route()
route.stations.add(new Station("stationOne"))
route.stations.add(new Station("stationTwo"))
route.save()
//now in db there are 2 stations. 

//now create new route with 2 stations, with one similar to already saved ('stationOne').
def route2 = new Route()
route2.stations.add(new Station("stationOne")) //<-- this one i want to be replaced
                                               // with the inDB one, if i save the route
                                               // in DB must be only one "stationOne"
                                               // and every route must point to it,
                                               // not own "stationOne", if the route saved
route2.stations.add(new Station("stationThree"))

route2.save()
//now i wish in DB there are only 3 stations.
//and route2 has both from DB. And the reference (in list) from route2 to "stationOne"
//inMemory object is now replaced with reference to inDB station object.
```

i could write code, like "replaceWithDBStationReferences(route)"
But my project is enough big, for testing such things in code.
is it possible to define this somewhere in domain? or any other solutions?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Added. But in this question i just want to know "how to" best practices, possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`findOrCreate`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrCreateBy.html) dynamic methods:

```
route2.stations.add(Station.findOrCreateByName("stationOne"))
```

`findOrCreateByName` is similar to `findByName` except that where the plain finder would return null (if nothing is found) the `findOrCreate` will create a new transient instance based on the query parameters, in this case a `new Station(name:'stationOne')`.

There's also [`findOrSaveBy...`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveBy.html) which does the same but also saves the new instance before returning it.

Comment: its not exact what i m looking for, but ok, if not in domain, than this way is much better :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use the existing Route from the DB you should  just need to fetch it first. Something like this:

```
def route = Route.findByName(name)
def stations = getNewAndModifiedStations()
stations.each { station ->
   def existingStation = route.stations.find { station.name?.equals(it.name) }
   if (existingStation) {
   // if station is found
       existingStation.updateProperties(station)
   } else {
     // new station here
     route.stations.add(station)
   }
}

route.save()
```

Comment: i need the existing stations. If i call route.save() it saves the stations again.. And i need something like  
 || stations cascade : "dont save exists stations, replace the references to it with already exists in db" ||
Should i test in code, for each route, if station exists, and replace the reference manually, than save the route?

Comment: i think my question was not enough good described. So i updated the question, to make sure what i want to know.